# Python Assign-Print statement?

Tags: python

So I'm writing some python scripts to help me do some simple calculations:

```
WireRadius = .455 / 1000 / 2  #m, 25AWG
CoilInnerRadius = 10.0 / 1000 / 2 #m
CoilOuterRadius = 20.0 / 1000 / 2 #m
CoilLength = 20.0 / 1000 #m
CoilVolume = 3.14 * (CoilOuterRadius**2 - CoilInnerRadius**2) * CoilLength #m^3
print "CoilVolume: " + str(CoilVolume)
WireCrossSection = 3.14 * WireRadius**2 #m^2
print "WireCrossSection: " + str(WireCrossSection)
LengthOfWire = CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2 #m
print "LengthOfWire: " + str(LengthOfWire)
```

Now, I want the script to print out all the intermediate components, so I can see what is going on. If I screw up, this will also let me pinpoint the line where my math is wrong, because that's when the numbers become nonsensical.

However, this is clearly not very DRY, since I am writing out each variable name not once, not twice, but three times:

```
LengthOfWire = CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2 #m
print "LengthOfWire: " + str(LengthOfWire)
```

If I was typing this into the interactive shell, it would automatically spit out the values of the intermediate components back at me:

```
>>> LengthOfWire = CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2 #m
14.491003502
```

which is quite nice, because the assignment statement is preserved meaning I know exactly what the next value is. However, the problem with putting it in the interactive shell is that making changes and re-running the whole script (which is a few dozen calculations long) is tedious. Is there any way to achieve this functionality in scripts run via python script.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def debug(val):
  logging.debug('DEBUG: %r', val)
  return val

 ...
LengthOfWire = debug(CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2)
```

Don't forget to set up your [logger](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

An improved version of Ignacio's function:

```
import logging

def debug(val, label=None):
  """Prints a debug message consisting of a value and an optional label."""
  if label is None:
    logging.debug('DEBUG: %r', val)
  else:
    logging.debug('DEBUG: %s = %r', label, val)
  return val

 ...
LengthOfWire = debug(CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2, label="Wire length")
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#module-pdb) to monitor the execution.  I doubt you'll want all those logging statements after you've worked-out the calculation.

Doug Hellmann has [a nice worked-out example of using pdb](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pdb/index.html#module-pdb).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `debug` function is probably best, but if you really want to do the assignments without obscuring the expressions it is actually possible using metaclasses:

```
class print_dict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not key.startswith('_'):
            print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


class MetaPrint(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        return print_dict()
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
        return result


def foo(x):
    class ShowMe(metaclass=MetaPrint):
        WireRadius = x / 1000 / 2  #m, 25AWG
        CoilInnerRadius = 10.0 / 1000 / 2 #m
        CoilOuterRadius = 20.0 / 1000 / 2 #m
        CoilLength = 20.0 / 1000 #m
        CoilVolume = 3.14 * (CoilOuterRadius**2 - CoilInnerRadius**2) * CoilLength #m^3
        WireCrossSection = 3.14 * WireRadius**2 #m^2
        LengthOfWire = CoilVolume / WireCrossSection / 2 #m

foo(.455)
```

Then when you've got everything sorted just delete the `class ShowMe...` line and unindent the class body. The main limitation with this is that you cannot `return` from inside the class body, so if you need a return value you'd have to give it a name and e.g. `return ShowMe.LengthOfWire` at the end.